# Limit of a differentiable function with conditions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let  $\,f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function, so $\,f(0)=0$ and $\left(1+x^{2}\right)f'(x)\geq 1+f^{2}(x).$ Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty }f(x).$

Comment: As in many of the questions you have asked before: what have *you* tried?

Comment: I tried to use Lagrange

Comment: Can you add this information, and where that led you, to the question?

Comment: Do you know you can click for an answer as the chosen answer? Usually it's a way to say thank you.

Comment: @RafaBudría One can say thank you by simply upvoting any helpful answer, one might also accept an answer, but we should make it crystal clear that it is **not a requirement** that any asker must upvote every answer to his/her question, nor is it required of any asker that s/he accept one and only one answer.

Comment: @amWhy, my comment was cordial: it seemed as the user didn't know he/she can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearranging the assumption, we get 
$$ (\arctan f(x))' = \frac{f'(x)}{1+f^2(x)} \ge \frac{1}{1+x^2} = (\arctan x)', $$
then by integration, 
$$ \arctan f(x) - \arctan f(0) \ge \arctan x - \arctan 0, $$
$$ f(x) \ge x \to \infty. $$

The above works for $f \in C^1$. For $f$ merely differentiable, one can instead use Cauchy's mean value theorem - for every $x>0$ there is some $0< y < x$ such that 
$$ \frac{\arctan f(x)}{\arctan x} = \frac{\arctan f(x) - \arctan f(0)}{\arctan x - \arctan 0} = \frac{(\arctan f)'(y)}{(\arctan)'(y)} \ge 1. $$
hence $f(x) \ge x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Building intuition.** If there is an answer, it can only be $\infty$.

   *Why?* Because the simplest example one can come up with is $f\colon x\mapsto x$. It satisfies all constraints, and $\lim_{\infty} f = \infty$. So the only possible answer is $\infty$.
2. **Proving it.**

   - Note that any $f$ satisfying the assumptions is increasing, since $f'(x) \geq \frac{1}{1+x^2} > 0$ for all $x$. So any such $f$ converges in $[0,\infty]$.
   - Actually, it has to converge in $[\frac{\pi}{2},\infty]$, since
     $$f(x)  = \int_0^x f'(t)\, dt \geq \int_0^x \frac{ dt}{1+t^2} = \arctan x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
   - Idea: ***incomplete***, to be finished. Assume by contradiction $\ell\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \lim_\infty f < \infty$ (by the above, we also know $\ell > 0$). Then there exists $x_0>0$ such that $f(x)\geq \frac{\ell}{2}$ for all $x\geq x_0$, and
     $$\begin{align}
     f(x)  &= f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)\, dt \geq \frac{\ell}{2}+ \int_{x_0}^x \frac{(1+\frac{\ell^2}{4}) dt}{1+t^2} \\
     &= \frac{\ell}{2}+(1+\frac{\ell^2}{4})(\arctan x - \arctan x_0)
     \end{align}$$
     Use this (taking the limit on both sides to get an inequation of the form $\ell \geq \Phi(\ell)$) to derive a contradiction. So $\boxed{\ell = \infty}$.